# LongClickListener not working

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I want to add longClickListener for my every button in my fragment.For this, i wrote this code, i call it in OnCreate().My project is Tabbed Activity.

I have implement OnLongClickListener in my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener
```

And i also have onLongClick method in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {.......}
```

Here is my method in onCreate() ;

```
public void InflateFragments(){

        final RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Page1Lay);
        View viev = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, lay, false);


        for(int i  = 0; i < IDs.length; i++){
            Button button = (Button) viev.findViewById(IDs[i]);

            if(button != null)                    
                button.setOnLongClickListener(this);  
                Log.i("OK","Listener set on button : " + IDs[i]);
             }
    }
```

IDs, is a int array that include my buttons id's.This code can reach every button in my fragment and set OnLongClickListener for every button, because there is no exception or any error.I can se Log.i()'s message on console.

But when i run this code on virtual device, there is nothing happend when i clicked long.I do not know why.

My buttons are in a layout and my every button has ;

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

My main_activity.xml ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.aslan.rte3.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:background="@android:color/black">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="#E0DFDE">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#E0DFDE">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="..."
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try using button.setOnLongClickListener(getActivity());

Comment: Have you tried putting a log in onLongClick() and seen if it has fired?

Comment: Can you add the content of `activity_main.xml`?

Comment: @AritraRoy i have tried, and i have seen noting :)

Comment: @raktale i cant call getActivity(). How can i call that?

Comment: can you just check Wether button view was null or not , I suppose long click listener is not being set at all, try to put log or debug  probably button is null here.  setting Long click listener seems to be fine

Comment: one more question ,what exactly you are trying to achieve from inflateFragments method?? Is this method inside your activity ??

Comment: @RenuYadav buttons are not null, im sure because i can see Log.i(). if buttons have been null, i cant see that.

Comment: i have 8 fragments in my tabbed activiy.This code will scan my all fragments, and find my buttons in that fragment.Than set on click listener to buttons.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
View viev = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, lay, false);
```

try this:

```
View viev = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, lay, false);
```

Comment: did the log printed `Log.i("OK","Listener set on button : " + IDs[i]);` on this line?

Comment: yes ;I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624091
I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624092
I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624093
I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624094
I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624095
I/OK: Listener set on button : 2131624096

Answer (score 0):

Try this once;

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Log.e("ID", ""+v.getId());
    return true;
}
```

And, then check if the view's Id here is same as one the buttons.

Comment: i have wrote Toast message in onLongClick, but when i clicked long, there is no message shown

Comment: I was wondering, why you used 'Button button = (Button) viev.findViewById(IDs[i]);' Are there too many buttons? Try setting 'onLongClickListener()' to a single button first with it's id this way 'Button button = (Button) viev.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);'

Comment: @Journy, i mean, onLongClick do not work, do not called

Comment: No no I was trying to say, just set OnLongClickListener to a single button created and parsed using the same id assigned in .xml(layout) file. I mean to say, check if there's nothing wrong with the array, 'IDs[ ]'.

Comment: IDs array is true, it set with id which in  R.id folder if id starts with "button".

Comment: After `View viev = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, lay, false);`, do write `Button button = (Button) viev.findViewById(R.id.oneOfYourBtnId);` and `button.setOnLongClickListener(this);` then check if that particular button hits 'OnLongClick(View view)' method using Log. Can, you please do that and share the result with me?

Comment: it will be error., because Button button = (Button)viev.findViewById(R.id.oneOfYourBtnId);

Comment: it will be error., because Button button = (Button)viev.findViewById(R.id.oneOfYourBtnId); This code returns button if button you want is in fragment_page1, else turns null.In my app, there are 100 buttons in different fragment.Andi get all buttons id's to IDs array, so IDs array in a lot of button in different fragments, and these ids are mixed.So, if id which given to findById method is not a member of fragment_page1, it returns null and setOnLongClickList returns exception, and myy app will close.Can i explain :) its little complicated